# get oauth_token and oauth_token secret with twitter anywhere

Tags: javascript, oauth, twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter-anywhere

Is there any way to get oauth_token and oauth_token_secret after signin with twitter anywhere javascript API?
In Facebook javascript API, I can do `FB.getAuthResponse()['accessToken']` to get the access_token.
I am looking for similar way to get it using twitter javascript api

Answer (score 0):

Twitter does not use OAuth 2. You will need to implement an OAuth 1 client, fortunately there are many available. In the JavaScript world I prefer this one: https://github.com/bytespider/jsOAuth.